# Add extra faces to a extruded geometry using Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry

[image: Extruded geometry]
I have a geometry extruded from a SVG. Now I would like to add faces to the flat side of the geometry as you can see in the image added, the yellow grid. The extruded geometry can be of any shape.

How's the best way to doing this?

**UPDATE:**
I found out that the *tessellateModifier* splits faces in to smaller faces and with that I get sort of what I want. So that questions is now:

### How to tessellate on just one side?

```
var maxEdgeLength = 1; //Smaller makes more new faces
var times = 5; //Times to do the split of faces
var tessellateModifier = new THREE.TessellateModifier(maxEdgeLength);
for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    tessellateModifier.modify(geometry);
}
```

Comment: Do you have those vertices? You can create a polygon out of them.

Comment: I don't have the yellow ones. But they could be a grid of any size.